# OpenCV calcOpticalFlowPyrLK - how do I identify points that got tracked?

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I have a vector of `Point2f`. I want to track these points.

I also have a vector of meta information that contains Data about these points, for example what Object ID a point has.

At the beginning of my application. the points and meta information are filled. Which means the size of the meta data is the same size as the point vector.

Now I encounter a problem:

When I pass my points into `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`, the count of `status`, `err` and `nextPts` is unequal the count of the points I passed in and thus unequal the size of the meta vector.

How am I supposed to identify the points I pass in and get out with my meta information?

```
std::vector<uchar> status;
cv::Mat err;

std::vector<cv::Point2f> currentPoints;
TermCriteria criteria = TermCriteria((TermCriteria::COUNT) + (TermCriteria::EPS), 10, 0.03);
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(lastFrames.front(), frame, keyframePoints, currentPoints, status, err, Size(15,15), 2, criteria);
// after that:
//status.size() != keyframePoints.size()
//keyframePoints.size() != currentPoints.size()
//currentPoints.size() != meta.size()
```

Comment: What are some of the size values that you got for status, err, and nextPts?

Comment: @JordanPaldino keyFramePoints=6569, status=4554, err= 4554, currentPoints=4554 for example

Comment: could you provide a self-contained test case, a [mre] (including one or two pictures)?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz unfortunately I can't. It's a realtime application and used on iOS.